# A data extraction project with wikipedia dumps

Tags: data-mining, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am learning about data mining. My dream is to develop a system that receives a small text (a few sentences) and delivers a dictionary with phrases from the text and most relevant tags from a database. For example,

Input (from NYTimes website): 
"LOS ANGELES — The Walt Disney Company, in an effort to address concerns about entertainment’s role in childhood obesity, plans to announce on Tuesday that all products advertised on its child-focused television channels, radio stations and Web sites must comply with a strict new set of nutritional standards."

Output:

```
"LOS ANGELES" : [USA, California, Los_Angeles, city], 
"The Walt Disney Company": [Walt_Disney, Corporation, USA, movies, entertainment], 
"childhood obesity" : [childhood, illness, health],
"all products advertised": [product, advertisement,
"television channel": [TV, broadcast, advertisement],
"radio station": [Radio, broadcast, advertisement],
"web sites": [Web, broadcast, advertisement]
```

I have downloaded the english and spanish wikipedia dumps. So far, I managed to extract all the titles, and the words from the titles, with python, lxml, and nltk. Now, I am developing a program to find the links network between the articles in the dumps, the links to external sites, etc. Also, I am thinking about the extraction of infoboxes. Also, I am going publish the python code in github this week. Now, I am commenting and testing it.

What advice can you give me? Do you think this proposal is feasible?

Comment: I advise making it easy for someone interested in the project to be able to download small, 30M chunks from the wikimedia dumps. Those things are too huge to require people to download in their entirety if they are just idly curious...

Comment: yes it is feasible, but hard to optimize. Talk to wikipedia developers on irc #mediwiki

Comment: If you want to know links and categories for some article, there are special dumps for that. They use a different format, though (SQL).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to check out [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About), instead of manually processing raw Wikipedia dumps. DBpedia harvests Wikipedia and structures it in order to make the relations easy to query.

There are also other projects which scrape Wikipedia, e.g. [Semantic MediaWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) and [Freebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebase_%28database%29). [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordnet) might also be a useful source of information. It is dictionary/thesaurus which shows many types of relations between words.